# How to mount multiple Windows remote directories and change a file on each?

Tags: windows, mount, remote-access, remote

I need to mount about 30 windows directories. I have a file that I need to change in c:\users\test\file.txt. the file currently contains text and I need to overwrite it with another file (it is a configuration file for a program)

I have administrator username and password for each of these computers.

I really want to avoid going around to each computer and changing this manually but I am not sure how to. If there is a way I can mount these directories one by one and automatically overwrite the file, close the connection, and start the connection to the next computer that would be great. If there is a script you can suggest or a way of doing this I would really appreciate the input. thank you.

Comment: One solution is to use [PsTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you also have each computername, you can do this all remotely.

Enter the administrative networkshare C$ on the pc.

For example, if the pcname is: `PC-001`, then you would point explorer to the following path: `\\PC-001\C$\Users\test`

You can also access this path through a .cmd script by using the following commands:

I will assume Z: is not in use on your computer. Change Z: to any free driveletter.

```
:: make drive mapping
NET USE Z: \\PC-001\C$

::copy the file
COPY c:\Users\Test\file.txt Z:\Users\test\file.txt

:: unmap the drive
NET USE /d Z:
```

Now, you can of course repeat the above as many times for different computers.

The only thing that will be hard is entering the correct path on the destination computer if the usernames are not similar on each pc and you really need to store the file in their profile folder.

Also, you will need to run the script with the right network credentials, using `Run as different user...` To do this, right click the file while holding shift and choose Run as different user... If your user already has administrative rights on the network, you do not need to do this.

If these computers are part of a domain, it may be easier to program something through the logon script though.